# Is there a way to get the current child while using children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some buttons in my div, and when pressed 1, I want to change the styling of others, so only one item gets highlighted each time. My problem occurs because they have different colours. Thus, specifically, I need to get the current child's border-color and assign it to color of itself.

Here is my example:

```
$('.myItem').click(function( 
    $(this).parent().children().not(this).css('background-color', 'white');

    $(this).parent().children().not(this).css('color', $('*').css('border-color'));
)}
```

Is there a way to get the current child just like we use $(this)?

Comment: what do you mean current child?  if you want to apply a style to all the elements except `this` then just apply the style to all the buttons then remove the style to `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` on `children()` and then reference the `child`.

```js
$('.myItem').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children().map((id, child) => {
    console.log(id, child);
    $(child).css('color', '#f00');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p class="myItem">click me</p>
  <p>greetings</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: @senty I also added some jquery in as well to further prove the concept. - enjoy.